# How are default arguments handled in pyqt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

In Qt, you have this routine (among others) in QAbstractItemModel

```
bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
```

Which basically instantiates a new QModelIndex every time it is called if parent is not specified.

In python, the meaning of the same line is vastly different: only one QModelIndex would be instantiated and shared at every call

The point that is not clear to me is how this difference is handled in PyQt. The [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemmodel.html) seems to be automatically generated from the C++ one, with the result that the default argument instantiation uses the same syntax, but with a completely different meaning, leaving the issue unaddressed.

This problem of course carries on to custom reimplementations in PyQt of the QAbstractItemModel. Should you declare

```
 def insertRows(self, row, count, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
```

or

```
 def insertRows(self, row, count, index=None):
```

and then instantiate a new QModelIndex if index is None?

Comment: If you use `QModelIndex()` as default argument you can use `isValid()` method, if you use `None` you have to check for none then `isValid()` method so I'd recommend using `QModelIndex` instance as default value. This is the only difference as far as I know.

Comment: @rebus, as I understand, the requirement is: if no actual argument for `parent` is passed, then assign new instance of `QModelIndex` - do not use existing one. @Stefano, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool insertRows(int row, int count, 
                const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
```

and

```
def insertRows(self, row, count, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
```

Both of these examples result in invalid index instance.

### What is an invalid [QModelIndex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmodelindex.html#details)?

> An invalid model index can be constructed with the QModelIndex
>   constructor. Invalid indexes are often used as parent indexes when
>   referring to top-level items in a model.

### Does [insertRows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows) need a new invalid instance each time it is called?

> In case of the [insertRows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows) function the base class implementation
>   of this function does nothing and returns false.

The quote means that if you use `QAbstractItemModel` you need to implement `insertRows` yourself.
This means you need to call [beginInsertRows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) which takes the parent argument.

**When parent indexes are involved, C++ side of Qt will not care which instance is given**. As long as it is invalid it will mean the current item is in the top level of the model and has no parent.

**`QAbstractItemModel` should not delete any indexes that it hasn't created by it self**.
In C++, the parent argument is passed as `const` reference and thus will not be deleted or changed by `beginInsertRows` function.

Segmentation faults that could occur if C++ instance was deleted while it was still referenced in Python are your biggest problem I think.

Now in Python, the argument created in function definition will usually have long life span, and **there could be ways for the instance to get deleted *that I am unaware* of but generally you should be safe.**

If you are worried about this simply create new instance each time.

[index = index or QtCore.QModelIndex()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213716/327317)

But for what it's worth I don't remember having trouble creating index instances in function definitions and I have done so in several occasions.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in my program, with the begin and end added:

```
def insertRows(self, row, count, index): 
  self.beginInsertRows(index, row, count)
  """ Your stuff here



  """
  self.endInsertRows()
```

Also check out the [pyside docs](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/index.html), because they usually do a much better job than the pyqt ones, and are under the LGPL so you can use it for buisness. IIRC it is the same result, but different implementation under different licenses.

Answer (score 0):

First, reasons to do it my way:

1. Requirement is that call to `insertRows` "instantiates a new QModelIndex every time it is called if parent is not specified".
2. Python assigns a default value for keyword argument only once - not at every call.

So here is my solution:

```
def insertRows(self, row, count, index=None):
    index = index or QtCore.QModelIndex()
    # do other stuff
```